# How to test file download feature through BrowserStack automation

Tags: file-upload, automated-tests, browserstack

I am testing an automation test case of a web application through browserstack. There is a button on web application after clicking on which zip file should get installed on local system and then I want to store that downloaded file on another local path.

As BrowserStack executes test cases on remote desktop/virtual machine, my test case is getting failed because zip file is not getting downloaded on my local system.

Is there any way to write a java code to transfer downloaded file from browserstack location into local system ?

I have referred below documentation to use browserstack_executor but I am getting error 'WebDriverException : browserstack_executor command not found'

https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/test-file-download#Other_Browsers

Answer (score 0):

Since Browserstack runs your test on the devices hosted on their remote devices I do not think that the file could be transferred to your local machine.

You could however look forward to exploring some cURL commands that could help you achieve your use case to some extent.

Thanks.